# check ng-if for a value and if not show another thing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting a response from server into a Json (containing color.mix and color.pure) and passed directly to the template, so, in this template I need to know if a value is coming in order to show it or show other value

```
<span ng-if="color.mix">{{color.mix}}</span>
```

but, if this value is not coming I need to show the 'pure' value, so I did (wrong!!)

```
<span ng-if="!color.mix">{{color.pure}}</span>
<span ng-if="color.mix">{{color.mix}}</span>
```

but, when both are coming, both are being showed.

How can I achieve this goal?

(Angular 1.6)

Comment: The idea of an `ng-else` has been tossed around for a while now, but as far as I know nothing is official. You may be interested in `ng-switch`, though. As it meets your criteria. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<span>{{color.mix ? color.mix : color.pure}}</span>
```

Comment: if you know you'll get one or the other

Comment: yep, you know that at least the 'pure' is coming allways, so, this answer was the most helpful! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check for both the conditions

```
<span ng-if="!color.mix && color.pure">{{color.pure}}</span>
<span ng-if="color.mix && !color.pure">{{color.mix}}</span>
```

if you want to do it in one line using a ternary operator, you could simply do,

```
<span>{{color.mix ? color.mix : color.pure}}</span>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);
app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.color = {
      pure: "test"
    };
  }
]) ;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">
<head>
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="dobController">
<span>{{color.mix ? color.mix : color.pure}}</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for both resolutions! but @tcrite was the first one to solve my problem! but, thanks for take the time to read my noob question!